# Compare tool with command line for mac

Tags: comparison, diff

I am looking for command line tool to do diff between two HTML files.
I have analysed kdiff3/command line of bbedit but my problem is dont want to open any GUI.
I want to write a java program to call command line options of the diff program to compare html files and save result in a different file or probably show in a report file.
Any pointers will be very helpful

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 15):

If you have xcode installed, you can call up `opendiff`, it's a (graphical) compare tool from the command line. From it's [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opendiff.1.html):

```
opendiff file1 file2 [-ancestor ancestorFile] [-merge mergeFile]
opendiff dir1 dir2 [-ancestor ancestorDirectory] [-merge mergeDirectory]
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought mac had diff built in.  Have you tried using diff from the mac terminal?

Comment: Didnt knew about it Started looking into it.

Comment: it was good but started using Java page diff open source and customized it.

Comment: Yes macOS does have `diff` baked in, but `opendiff` is a lot easier to see the differences in if there's anything complicated. `opendiff` is available if you have `Xcode` installed, which is [Apple’s integrated development environment (IDE)](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) for macOS.